# Formset invalid but 'Save' saves parent model and closes page

Tags: python, django, formset

I have a formset `payment` on a parent model `invoice`. If the user enters a payment but forget the payment date (which is required) the page still saves the invoice and **then closes**.

I can see from form_valid that `formset.is_valid()` is False. I can see the error raised if I print it in console: `[{}, {}, {'paymentdate': ['This field is required.']}, {}]`. I can even see the validation show up on the page right before is closes.

How do I keep the page from closing when there is a validation error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, form fields of formsets won’t include the required attribute as that validation may be incorrect when adding and deleting forms.
>   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets/

Formsets are very limited in capabilities and resource inefficient, so it's best not to use them. You'd have to overwrite your view to customize the workflow.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on an alternative to formsets?

Comment: I'd rather just use AJAX Javascript and add/edit each form one by one with CRUD views.